How to force selected faces of an object to point toward one direction
I obtained a mesh by RealityCapture photogrammetry and the edges of my object have faces pointing everywhere (a very rough surface).
This object is a hood for my drone body.
At that time the only way I found to make the small surfaces of those edges to be flat is to orient face by face through the same direction (perpendicular to the edge body) by using the blender R command.
I'm searching the way to constrain the faces I selected to point to the same direction..!...?
I have to add that of course modifying the normals of the selected faces apply only to render and not to the geometry, so that doesn't apply to this case, unfortunately!

Hello and welcome to BSE. Can you share a screenshot? You can try select faces and press S to scale then press X, Y, or Z depending on which axis the faces are roughly pointing then press 0 and Enter

Sorry I;m a new user on this Forum and I don't know how to send a snapshot of the screen of my PC. I'll try your advices soon !

Does this link help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post ?

You can try a Smooth modifier too, that will smoothen the surface, although it will reduce the total volume of your object
